# Reduce speed of following image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm making a game where a gif is following the cursor. Is there any way to reduce the speed so that the image that follows the cursor moves at a constant (but slower) speed than the cursor itself?

Basically right now the gif I assigned is acting link a replacement cursor. I want the gif to follow and catch up to the cursor at its own speed.

Thanks

```js
<script>
document.querySelector(".testsite").onmousemove = (e) => {
  const x = e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft;
  const y = e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop;
 
  e.target.style.setProperty("--x", `${x}px`);
  e.target.style.setProperty("--y", `${y}px`);
};
 
</script>
```

```css
<style>
body {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
 
.testsite {
/* container */
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  appearance: none;
  background: grey;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  cursor: none;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: black;
}
.testsite span {
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.testsite::before {
  --size: 0;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--x);
  top: var(--y);
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-image: url("html5.gif");
  animation-duration: 1s;

  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

</style>
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="testsite">
  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the x and y coordinate operations of your js into a function and then add a `setTimeout` to that function to run it every 100ms or how ever long you want the delay to be.  Check it out here, note I also removed `pointer:none;` from `.testsite` :

```js
document.querySelector(".testsite").onmousemove = (e) => {
  const x = e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft;
  const y = e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop;
  
  function runInt() {
  e.target.style.setProperty("--x", `${x}px`);
  e.target.style.setProperty("--y", `${y}px`);
  }
 setTimeout(runInt, 100);
};
```

```css
body {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
 
.testsite {
/* container */
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  appearance: none;
  background: grey;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em;

  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: black;
}
.testsite span {
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.testsite::before {
  --size: 0;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--x);
  top: var(--y);
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-image: url("https://www.springbrookanimalcarecenter.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Springbrook_iStock-612247460-150x150.jpg");
  animation-duration: 1s;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="testsite">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```